# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , " when trying to access javascript object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

In aliases.js, I'm trying to access the 'SELECT_HOST' property value from the imported actionTypes object. However, this results in a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ," error, as per Webpack. I'm not able to pinpoint what is the syntax error in `actionTypes.SELECT_HOST` which is standard dot-notation way to access the object property's value.

actionTypes.js:

```
const actionTypes = {
    SELECT_HOST : 'SELECT_HOST',
    INVOKE_ASSESSMENT : 'INVOKE_ASSESSMENT',
    RETRIEVE_ASSESSMENT : 'RETRIEVE_ASSESSMENT',
    RETRIEVE_OPTIONS : 'RETRIEVE_OPTIONS',
    RETRIEVE_RESULTS : 'RETRIEVE_RESULTS',
    UPDATE_OPTIONS : 'UPDATE_OPTIONS'
};

export default actionTypes;
```

aliases.js:

```
import actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';

const selectHost = (host) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, (tabs) => {
        host = new URL(tabs[0].url).hostname;
    });
    const action = {
        type: actionTypes.SELECT_HOST,
        host
    };
    return action;
};

export default {
    actionTypes.SELECT_HOST: selectHost
};
```

Webpack throws error:

```
ERROR in ./src/aliases/aliases.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,     (15:12)

  13 | 
  14 | export default {
> 15 |  actionTypes.SELECT_HOST: selectHost
     |             ^
  16 | };
```

Comment: I believe you may need to define `out = {}; out[actionTypes.SELECT_HOST] = selectHost; export default out;`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: No need for that two-step in ES2015+, if that's what the OP's trying to do.

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with `actionTypes.SELECT_HOST`? Yes, it's  a perfectly normal property access expression, but where you're doing it, a property access expression is invalid (hence the error).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the comments and your answer. I wasn't aware that property access expressions can't be used inside object literals. I'm defining certain constants as object values in actionTypes.js (which serves as an enums collection) and then exporting the values. Then, in other files, I'm accessing these values.

Comment: @Agrim: Good deal (you did say you were using the value at the end, I just wanted to be sure). And the good news is you can use those expressions now (in brackets). :-)

Comment: I wonder why the question got down-voted though... Any pointers? Not that I care so much about imaginary internet points, but I'd like to phrase my questions better in the future...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to use the **value** of `actionTypes.SELECT_HOST` as the property name in the object you're exporting, you can use computed property notation to do that (new as of ES2015, but then, so are many of the other things you're using, so...), note the `[]`:

```
export default {
    [actionTypes.SELECT_HOST]: selectHost
};
```

For instance, if `actionTypes.SELECT_HOST` contains the string `"foo"`, that would produce an object with a property named `foo` whose value was the value of `selectHost`.

Comment: Great, that worked indeed! Yes, I'm using ES2015 (although still in the process of learning it comprehensively), so a new thing to learn every day.

Answer (score 2):

Inside Object literal, key name cannot contain dot (.)